# How to programmatically set keybinding schemes in kde

Tags: kde-plasma, key-bindings

I'm making a automatic configuration script for kde and I want to replace the current keybindings with a key binding file of my own.

I found that there is a list of keybinding files in /usr/share/apps/kcmkeys directory all stored in .kksrc files, and I can define custom .kksrc files in ~/.kde/share/apps/kcmkeys directory. However, I don't know how to set kde to load one of these schemes automatically.

To change to use one of these key  binding files, I have to manually run

```
kcmshell keys
```

Then change the "Current Scheme" to one of these files using the gui. Is there a way to do this from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvm, I found a way to do this without using those files. 
/etc/kde3/kdeglobals has a list of global keybindings that override the kcmkeys, so I can just modify that file.